# Different between accessing a struct member XX by base address + offset of XX and struct_name->XX

Tags: c

I am using an open source library(Easy C State Machine). When I review the code, I found the struct is accessed by base address + offset of X, something like follows.

```
#define OFF_SET_OF_XX 1
#define GET_MEMBER(X, Y, Z) ((X)(*((X*)(((int*)(Y))+Z))))

typedef struct Foo {
int i;
int XX;
}Foo;

Foo *foo1 = alloc(...);
int j = GET_MEMBER(int, foo1, OFF_SET_OF_XX);
```

instead of:

```
Foo *foo1 = alloc(...);
int j = foo1->XX;
```

What's the difference between the above two? Any advantage of the former one?

The library is written in ANSI C. But it is said that it can only support two architecture: 
x86 and amd64. Since I want to use it on another arch, I reviewed the source code and find the only architecture-related code is the OFF_SET_OF_XXs.

Comment: The first one is the way to go on an obfuscated code contest.

Comment: Why would you _every_ write something like that? That's throwing type safety right out of the window. Might as well use assembler... Just stick with `->XX`! (Also, why is the offset 2 and not 1, as `Foo` is essentially `int[2]`?)

Comment: Sorry..It should be 1. I didn't notice it when I copyed the original code.

Comment: Why not tell us what open source library it is and tag the question with the name of the library?

Comment: Library name added. Cannot creat a new tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to point out the left-most cast to type `X` is not necessary so you could simplify it to:

```
#define GET_MEMBER(X, Y, Z) (*((X*)(((int*)(Y))+Z)))
```

Still, I don't see the purpose of using a macro like this.  It throws away type safety and the syntax is cumbersome.

The code that the compiler generates for the two different ways should be pretty similar, if not identical.  But what compiler and platform is this library supposed to be compiled on?  If there happened to be a performance gain from using `GET_MEMBER` in that compiler then that could be why they are using it.

**EDIT 1:** My guess is that the original author of the library did not know about structs and invented his own thing similar to structs using alloc, pointers, and macros.  Now that he has made the library open source, others are trying to convert it to use structs but there is a lot of code to convert and they haven't finished yet.

Comment: I would bet $10 that there has _never_ been a C compiler, at any optimization setting, where this construct is faster than simply accessing the element.

Comment: The "useless" cast does have one use: it prevents the expression from being an lvalue. Since the macro is called `GET_MEMBER`, I think this gives better semantics. Writing `GET_MEMBER(x,y,z)=a;` should be illegal.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I have seen with a legitimate purpose (borderline, IMO) is the Linux kernel's [container_of](http://www.google.com/search?q=container_of) macro.

But for the example you give, there is absolutely no reason to do this other than "the author is a moron".  It gains nothing in performance, sacrifices readability, and invites annoying bugs (e.g., what happens if somebody decides to change `i` to a `long` someday?)